# getElementById returns allways null if i search for new created Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

i want to duplicate one element and then assign to new id and names. my aim is later i want find that element again. here is an example:

```
<div id="contDiv">
<div style="float:left"> filename </div>
<div style="margin-left: 323px"> playtime(in Sek.) </div>
<div id="tl_Einst" class="editor-field">
<select id="Medianames" onchange="change(this)" name="TL_Medianame">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-    for="Filename">    </span>
<select id="playtime" class="playtime" name="playtime" disabled="">
</div>
<input id="More" type="button" onclick="Addfiles()" value="+">
</div>
```

in the runtime i duplicate the Element "tl_Einst"  with its children. then the user changes the content of the combox then i read them and send them to the server. later i get an answer. so i call the `GetelementById("newElementID")`, but i get always null, if search for the new created element. what can i do?

thank you

marek

Comment: GetelementById("#newElementID") should be used without "#". "#" is id selector in jQuery

Comment: i have corrected my post.

Comment: Why don't you show the actual JavaScript code!

Comment: Can you show your javascript?

Comment: Presumably the incorrect capitalisation (`GetelementById` should be `getElementById`) is just a typo in your question?

Answer (score 2):

The proper syntax is:

```
var el = document.getElementById("newElementID");
```

Typically, # is for JQuery or other javascript frameworks, or as @Quention mentions below, can also be used with document.querySelector.

Where are you adding the element to the DOM?  Could you include that code too?

Comment: `#` is selector syntax. You don't need a framework or a library to use it. `document.querySelector('#foo');`

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the update, forgot about that... updated.

Comment: @burkut OK thanks, it should be document.getElementById, with exact case syntax; the syntax above is off too.  Also, can you post the exact code where you add the element to the DOM? the issue may be there...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added it to the page?

getElementByID will only find an element in the DOM. You can either add it to the page or *simply* assign it to a variable.

```
var newElementID= document.createElement("p");
```

You can now find it in your code with `newElementID` even if it's not in the page.

Comment: please look at my Post again. i am sorry for that i edites my post again and again.

Comment: Is this supposed to be in quotes?:
`document.getElementById("SpielDauerstr.toString()");`.
Try `document.getElementById(SpielDauerstr.toString());`

Comment: no that was only one try, because it dosn't work. i have changed it now. but the result is same....